# String helper; arrays and substr

Tags: php, string

My problem is that I am using the random string creator shown below, I am not using 'alpha', I am using 'fourlet'. The only problem is that this in an array and that

```
substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
```

doesn't work as a random creator for an array of data. Can anyone please help?

Below is the full code for the helper.

```
{
function random_string($type = 'alnum', $len = 8)
{
    switch($type)
    {
        case 'basic'    : return mt_rand();
            break;
        case 'alnum'    :
        case 'numeric'  :
        case 'nozero'   :
        case 'alpha'    :

                switch ($type)
                {
                    case 'alpha'    :   $pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                        break;
                    case 'fourlet'  :   $pool = array('my', 'fun', 'zone', '12', '24', '37');
                        break;
                }

                $str = '';
                for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++)
                {
                    $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
                }
                return $str;
            break;
        case 'unique'   :
        case 'md5'      :

                    return md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
            break;
        case 'encrypt'  :
        case 'sha1' :

                    $CI =& get_instance();
                    $CI->load->helper('security');

                    return do_hash(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE), 'sha1');
            break;
    }
}
```

}

So

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some changes. Hope this will help you.

```
 <?php
```

// $input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
// $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
// echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
// echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";

function random_string($type = 'alnum', $len = 8)
{
    switch($type)
    {
    case 'basic'    : return mt_rand();
        break;
    case 'alnum'    :
    case 'numeric'  :
    case 'nozero'   :
    default:

```
    switch ($type)
    {
    case 'alpha'    :   $pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        break;
    case 'fourlet'  :   $pool = array('my', 'fun', 'zone', '12', '24', '37');
        break;
    }

    $str = '';
        if(gettype($pool)=='string'){
            for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
                $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
            }
        }   
        else if(gettype($pool)=='array'){       
            $rand_keys = array_rand($pool,4);
         $str=$pool[$rand_keys[0]].$pool[$rand_keys[1]].$pool[$rand_keys[2]].$pool[$rand_keys[3]];

        }       


    return $str;
    break;
case 'unique'   :
case 'md5'      :

    return md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    break;
case 'encrypt'  :
case 'sha1' :

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('security');

    return do_hash(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE), 'sha1');
    break;
}
```

}

var_dump(random_string('fourlet',8));

?>

Comment: hmmm. sadly this is returning a string of "yoymoeym" instead of the actual words :(

Comment: So you want the actual words?

Comment: yes please! Sorry, should've been more clear. each of the array values 'my,' 'fun' etc need to stay as a whole word or the number needs to stay as '12' or '24' and can't mix. So possible outcomes such as   'zone12my37' or 'funmy3724'. :)

Comment: Does it suits your requirements?

Comment: Worked a charm! You, Mr Rohit Kumar Choudhary are a legend and deserve a reward